# \newcommand{\name}{Name} to change a keyword in different versions

Tags: macros

Well, I'm using

```
\newcommand{\Name}{Name }
```

so I can change the name for different versions of my pdf.
When I use it like {Name }, with a space bar, sometimes in the text it gives 2 spaces, and sometives gives 1. "Name  Age" wrong or "Name Age" The way I want to be
But if I use it like {Name}, without a spacebar they just unify words. like "NameAge".again wrong

I'd like to know if someone know how to solve, or another way to just change the command for a word that it is not a new command maybe.

Comment: Define it as `\newcommand{\Name}{Name}` and *always* use it as `\Name{}`. Then you can insert it in your document and get consistent spacing around it. You should provide examples of where your usage fails.

Comment: @Werner That solved my problem. Thank you. =]
I wasn't puting a {} at the end of the command.